# Can I get locale format for apex:outputText?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I know that you can format a date like this:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}">
    <apex:param value="{!contact.Birthdate}" /> 
</apex:outputText>
```

However, my application will be distributed to multiple countries. On some (such as mine), date format is `dd/MM/yyyy`, but on others (such as in the US) the format is `MM/dd/yyyy`.

Is there a way I can tell Visualforce to use the locale's short date format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apex param based formating is based on Java's [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html):

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, date, short}">
    <apex:param value="{!contact.Birthdate}" /> 
</apex:outputText>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't provide date format according to user's locale. (see here for more: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/476/visualforce-locale-specific-date-format )

Comment: Sorry, nothing personal, I just don't like when the accepted answer contains answer that is incorrect. Besides that, I've also lost 1 point for downvoting. For me not the points are most important but the quality of SO :-). Also, I have posted an answer that is actually working, so that's not impossible to do in Salesforce. Please upvote it if you also care for the quality of SO community.

Comment: Easy mate, no need to be sarcastic ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The only solution to this issue that is actually working correctly was originally posted on http://mindfiresfdcprofessionals.wordpress.com/2013/10/25/how-to-dispaly-locale-formatted-datetime-in-visual-force/. I'm posting below code just in case the link will suddenly disappear:

You have to create new VF component called `LocaleDate`:

```
<apex:component access="global" controller="LocaleDateController">
<apex:attribute assignTo="{!dateValue}" description="The Date value to be rendered based upon the user's
               locale" name="date_Value" type="Date"></apex:attribute>
       {!TimeZoneValue}
</apex:component>
```

Its controller:

```
public with sharing class LocaleDateController {

    public Date dateValue{get;set;}

    public String getTimeZoneValue() {
        if( dateValue != null ) {
            String localeFormatT = dateValue.format();
            return localeFormatT;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then use such component like that:

```
<c:LocaleDate date_Value="{!TODAY()}"/>
```

It is working on any date value you enter, not necessarily sObject field. The whole idea is based on fact, that `Date.format()` function is creating String based on locale of current user. You can create in the same way wrapper controllers for DateTime and Decimal datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are assigning the variable of type date in the *value* attribute, it should automatically handle the locale for you. So you don't need to format it explicitly.

Comment: Yes, but default format, if you don't specify, is *medium*. I wanted to change it to *short* without losing locale support.